# Shared Preference Always Get Old Value In Retrofit Interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger-hilt

I am new in dagger hilt. So I just created a module that life as same as Application (SingletonComponent) like this.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object SharedPrefModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPref(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : SharedPrefs{
        return SharedPrefs(context)
    }
}
```

And then using the SharedPref in Network Module like this. (See the prefs parameter)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttp: OkHttpClient) : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().apply {
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            client(okHttp)
            baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
        }.build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttp(pref: SharedPrefs) : OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            addInterceptor(RequestInterceptor(pref))
        }.build()
    }

}
```

Inside the RequestInterceptor is like this:

```
class RequestInterceptor(private val pref: SharedPrefs) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val token = pref.getToken()
        val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", token)
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
}
```

I start the app without login (it means the prefs.getToken()) will return empty. But the problem is, even i have logged in and the token successfully saved, the pref.getToken() still return empty. I think there is a problem with instance-ing the sharedPrefs, since it singleton.

But how do I *refresh the shared preference* instance, so the Interceptor will always get the updated value of shared pref?

*If I want to get new value of the shared pref so the Interceptor can work, I need to close the app and then swipe/clear from task manager*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed by adding this in NetworkModule

```
    @Provides
    fun provideRequestInterceptor(prefs: SharedPrefs) : RequestInterceptor {
        return RequestInterceptor(prefs)
    }
```

and the RequestInterceptor like this:

```
class RequestInterceptor constructor(private val pref: SharedPrefs) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val token = pref.getToken()
        val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", token)
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
}
```

And then when providing theh okHttpClient, I change the function like this:

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttp(requestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor) : OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
        }.build()
    }
```